# Booting FreeBSD using grub2 on uefi machine

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I just installed FreeBSD 10.3 on an HP 450-a114. The install went smoothly with no issues. The machine has Windows 10, Linux Mint, and an LFS distro. In the past (on the older BIOS-only machines), all I have had to do is add a menu entry to a grub file, run update-grub, and then FreeBSD would boot Using grub2. The machine I am on now is uefi, and I cannot get FreeBSD to boot. Windows and Linux boot fine though. Everything is on a single drive. Here are my partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 -> Some uefi partition (label: /boot/efi)
/dev/sda2 -> Some Windows partition
/dev/sda3 -> Windows 10
/dev/sda7 -> My LFS distro
/dev/sda6 -> Linux Mint
/dev/sda8 -> Some efi partition installed by FreeBSD (label: EFI)
/dev/sda9 -> FreeBSD
/dev/sda10 -> FreeBSD swap
/dev/sda4 -> Windows recovery image
/dev/sda5 -> Windows recovery image.
```

If anyone needs any type of command line output, I will be happy to post it.

Comment: Have you tried chainloading sda8? [Archwiki on grub](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#FreeBSD_menu_entry)

Answer (score 1):

So `/dev/sda1` is probably the EFI system partition used by Windows, LFS and Mint. You can boot into them because the relevant files for these operating systems are inside `/dev/sda1` and so is GRUB. Therefore, GRUB can detect them.

However, the FreeBSD installation has created it's own EFI system partition in `/dev/sda8` and this is the reason why `update-grub` doesn't work because the GRUB in `/dev/sda1` isn't able to find the relevant EFI files in `/dev/sda1`.

You can try moving the relevant EFI files in `/dev/sda8` created by FreeBSD to `/dev/sda1`, edit them to reflect the changes, and try running `update-grub` again.

On another note, why install so many operating systems on so many partitions? Using a virtualization solution like `qemu` or `VirtualBox` might be a better option.

Comment: I will try that. I am very familiar with virtual machines, but my computer is not the highest quality, so I can only run 32-bit virtual machines, and even these are SO slow.

Comment: So, I just went into the machines boot device options as I was booting, I found a weird efi entry, hit, and it booted (I had not moved any files like you suggested). Is there are way to get grub to do the same thing?

Comment: @pdf4664 Yes, you can use your UEFI boot menu to boot into either of the operating systems. You can try to move your FreeBSD EFI files in `/dev/sda8` to `/dev/sda1` and run `update-grub` in either Mint or LFS. I think that should work.